# Why does the convolution of two arrays in MATLAB result in ‘NaN’ values?

Tags: matlab, nan, convolution, wavelet

I am trying to compute the convolution of a curve with a scaled wavelet. Using the MATLAB convolution function https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html, the result has a large number of 'NaN' values in the beginning, and I'd like to understand where these are coming from.

My instinct with convolution is that this should not be the case as I have defined upper bounds at each point of the convolution. The way I visualize this convolution is that the wavelet is flipped, and then moved from left to right over the curve. As it moves, the area below the intersection of the wavelet with the curve is what is stored in the output. If this is the case, the resulting output should exist and be positive at all points of the convolution except where there is no overlap and the result is 0.

```matlab
% The curve is a set of responses to presented stimuli,
% and the following is an example:

curve = [0.0500, 0.1000, 0.1500, 0.2000, 0.3000, 0.5000, 0.8000;
 11.6465, 14.8354, 5.0695, 0.4856, 0.5858, 0.2863, 0.3864];

% The scaled Mexican hat wavelet is as follows:

acuteness = 1000;
[mexh_y, mexh_x] = mexihat(-5,5,acuteness);
max_response = max(curve(2,:));
wav_x = mexh_x/100;
wav_y = mexh_y * (max_response+1);

% Here wav_x are the wavelet’s x-values and wav_y are the wavelet’s y-values.

% I interpolate the original curve to have more values as follows:

max_presentation = max(curve(1,:));
step = max_presentation/acuteness;
sf_vals_for_interpolation = [step:step:max_presentation];
interp_curve = interp1(curve(1,:),curve(2,:),sf_vals_for_interpolation);

% Now I’d like to perform a convolution:

conv_res = conv(interp_curve, wav_y);
```

As noted in the summary, the resulting convolution contains a number of 'NaN' values that I would like to understand.

Comment: Probably because `interp1` returns NaN values, easy check `any(isnan(interp_curve))`. See the [extrapolation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#btwp6lt-1-extrapolation) section of `interp1`.

Comment: Ah makes sense. I didn't notice initially there were NaN values in the interpolation. Thanks @rinkert !